# BigDecimal equivalent for php

Tags: php

I would like to do monetary unit calculation in php. In java, we have `BigDecimal` for this purpose as float and double cannot accurately represent the base 10 multiples that we use for money.

So what should i use in php?

Comment: Give [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) a try.

Answer (score 4):

PHP does not offer a `BigDecimal` equivalent out of the box. The closest thing you'll find is the [BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension, but it's quite low-level, and not as useful as a full-fledged BigDecimal class.

Instead, you can use a library called [brick/math](https://github.com/brick/math) that offers a [BigDecimal](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/master/src/BigDecimal.php) class, that's really close to Java's:

```php
use Brick\Math\BigDecimal;

$amount = BigDecimal::of('12.34');
echo $amount->multipliedBy(2); // 24.68
```

This library automatically uses the BCMath or GMP extensions when available, to speed up calculations (but works without them as well).

---

If you're specifically dealing with money though, I would advise you to try the [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) library. It's based on `brick/math` and handles exact monetary calculations:

```php
use Brick\Money\Money;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;

$amount = Money::of('12.34', 'USD');
echo $amount->dividedBy(2); // USD 6.17
echo $amount->dividedBy(3, RoundingMode::DOWN); // USD 4.11
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of these libraries.